# Pass lazy seq of file lines to function

Tags: clojure

Why does this bit of code not work?

```
(defn with-file [fname fn]
  (with-open [r (reader fname)]
    (fn (line-seq r))))

(with-file "data/input_d2" (fn [x] (map count x)))
```

I'm opening a file and while it is open I am passing a lazy sequence of lines to provided function.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error printing return value (IOException) at java.io.BufferedReader/ensureOpen (BufferedReader.java:122).
Stream closed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out.
Because the line seq is lazy, all operations on it return a lazy seq.
Therefore, my invocation of with-file function returns a lazy seq, which the REPL later tries to evaluate, but by then the file is already closed.

Therefore, we need to force evaluation of what is returned from the passed function.

```
(defn with-file [fname fn]
  (with-open [r (reader fname)]
    (doall (fn (line-seq r)))))

(with-file "data/input_d2" (fn [x] (map count x)))
```

Comment: Also, please clarify the arg names like `fn` => `f` or `the-fn`.  Also, I would wrap the `line-seq` directly with `doall` or `vec` like:  `(f (vec (line-seq r)))`.

Comment: Woudn't wrapping it directly with doall defeat the whole purpose of using a lazy sequence? It would all be loaded into memory

Comment: It would, but for most purposes it makes no difference.  Unless a lazy processing pipeline is truly required, I like to keep the `doall` or `vec` close to the place the makes it necessary.  If you put it at the end of a long processing chain, it is not obvious why it is there and it can lead to bugs when someone changes or removes an "unneeded" step.  Especially if the final step is as subtle as changing `mapv` to `map` for example.

Comment: I disagree with Alan here. I would stick with `doall` where you have it: around the body of code inside `with-open`. Directly wrapping `doall` around the `line-seq` code would force it all to be read into memory, and if the `fn` passed in reduces the data size -- as this `(map count x)` does -- you will want the laziness of that `line-seq` on very large files.

Comment: While lazyness is the reason, doing the doall all inside `with-file` has another risk - it expects `fn` to return a sequence. E.g. if explodes on `(with-file ... count)`. I'd rather expect `fn` to not be lazy.

Comment: cfrick makes a good point. If `fn` is eager, say a `reduce`, then you don't need `doall`, and for some eager functions (such as `count`) using `doall` would be wrong. This was always an issue for users of `clojure.java.jdbc` which required the `:result-set-fn` to be *eager*. You have to have a "contract" either way: require the `fn` to return a sequence (and keep `doall` where it is) or require the `fn` to be eager.

Comment: Is it possible to check if it is eager or lazy and then call do/doall respectively?